# Rails app which connects users to telnet server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, telnet

Right now there are very few [MUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD) clients that are up to date; most are graphically outdated and not user friendly.

I want to make a rails app where users can login and  connect to different MUDs (aka telnet servers). I know ruby has 'net/telnet' library but I am not sure how it works really or how to implement it with rails.

I am just unsure of how to allow a user interact back and fourth with a telnet server. Any suggestions on how to go about doing this?

I was only able to find [one source](https://workspaces.codeproject.com/theillbehaviored/mud-client-essentials) on this throughout the internet, but the documentation is poor and not suitable for my purposes. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually asking; telnet itself is pretty trivial. One of the old Ruby quizzes is a scriptable Ruby MUD client, #45, so it can't be *that* hard, no? http://rubyquiz.com/quiz45.html

Comment: (Unrelated, but I'm not sure how Rails is really involved here--seems *very* heavy as a simple gateway between a browser and a MUD, e.g., https://github.com/dannytatom/muddy.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding:

```
require 'net/telnet'
```

Is enough to use it. Then you can follow the documentation:

[http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/Net/Telnet.html#class-Net::Telnet-label-Examples](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/Net/Telnet.html#class-Net%3a%3aTelnet-label-Examples)

To implement it with rails you can create a class in libs which allows users to stablish connection to the desired host:

```
class TelnetClient
  require 'net/telnet'

  def self.new_connection(data_hash)
     Net::Telnet::new("Host" => data_hash["host"], 
                      "Timeout" => data_hash["timeout"],
                      "Prompt" => /[$%#>] \z/n)
  end

end

class ConnectionsController < ApplicationController

  def new_connection
     $localhost = TelnetClient.new_connection(connection_params)
     #whatever you need
  end

  def interactive_shell
    $localhost.cmd(params[:string])
    #other actions
  end

  private

  def connection_params
    params.require(:connection).permit(:host, :timeout)
  end
end
```

And create an nice interactive shell with javascript in the view to allow users to interact with the controller via ajax.

Comment: Can you describe how to connect to telnet through Ruby whereby I can simultaneously read and write data to a telnet host I am connected to?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not used to Telnet so I can't help you with this problem. Also, this sounds like another question, you might want to create another question to ensure better answers.
Did this one solved your previous problem?

Comment: Using a global variable to store the telnet connection seems like very bad idea to me.

Comment: Feel free to suggest a better one and I will improve the solution.

Comment: Thanks Jorge. I actually figured it all out on my own though! Have a good one mate